# How to stub URLSession in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, swift4, urlsession

I have been following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/the-complete-guide-to-network-unit-testing-in-swift-db8b3ee2c327) to stub out `URLSession`. [The example](https://github.com/koromiko/Tutorial/blob/master/NetworkingUnitTest.playground/Contents.swift#L45) was done by creating a protocol and extending the existing `URLSession`.

```
protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    typealias DataTaskResult = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void
    func dataTask(with request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
}

extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol {
    func dataTask(with request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
        return dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completionHandler) as URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
    }
}
```

The unit tests work as expected. But when I try to run the real thing, the URLSession -> datatask() gets into an infinite loop and it crashes. It seems to be that datatask() is calling itself.

What am I overlooking, please?

**UPDATE:**

```
protocol URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
    var originalRequest: URLRequest? { get }
    func resume()
}

extension URLSessionDataTask: URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {}
```

Comment: Did you define a MockURLSession class for testing?

Comment: Yes I did. Tests are running fine.  But when I want to use it in production by injecting `URLSession.shared` I get this endless loop.

Comment: and in production you return `URLSessionDataTask` instead of the protocol in the extension?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow what you mean. I have updated the question with `URLSessionDataTaskProtocol` implementation. This protocol is implemented for `MockUrlSession`. But the real `UrlSession` should be just using the URLSessionDataTask out of the box, correct? I don't think I have missed any dependency injection.

Comment: yes, that is what i ment :-)

Comment: See the real article here: http://masilotti.com/testing-nsurlsession-input/

Comment: One of the commenters notes that in Swift 4 it was infinite looping, but he made a fix.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Thanks Mike. I tried it but I still get the loop. It's quite strange, because he says that's a fix for Swift 4, but he is using `func dataTaskWithURL(with url)`, which seems like Swift 2.0 syntax, where it should be `dataTask(with: URL)`. Unless I am totally mistaken, his `dataTaskWithURL` is now a new custom method and isn't overriding anything in `URLSession` anymore. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the solution.  It’s fascinating as we missed the wood for the trees. There are two issues:

1) It seems that Swift 4 has changed the signature for `dataTask(with: NSURLRequest)` to `dataTask(with: URLRequest)`

Therefore the line in my opening question would only match to the Protocol's func signature, and it would never hit the `dataTask` inside `URLSession`, hence the infinite loop. To solve this issue I had to change `NSURLRequest` to `URLRequest` and refactor the code accordingly.

2) The signature remains vague, hence it is better to store the result as dataTask first with a cast to `URLSessionDataTask` and then return the variable.

**New refactored Code for Swift 4:**

```
typealias DataTaskResult = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void

protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
}

extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol {
    func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
        let task:URLSessionDataTask = dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
            (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in completionHandler(data,response,error) }) as URLSessionDataTask
        return task
    }
}
```

I also found I had to inject `URLSession.shared` as a singleton and not as `URLSession()`, otherwise it could crash.

Answer (score 3):

Came here to understand how to mock `URLSession` tasks such as `URLSessionDataTask`?

Circa Swift 5, it is *much* easier to mock the `URLProtocol` that `URLSession` is using to send the request.

See [Unit Testing URLSession using URLProtocol.](https://medium.com/@dhawaldawar/how-to-mock-urlsession-using-urlprotocol-8b74f389a67a)